# Is there a way to install a NuGet package without all of its dependencies?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

In a Visual Studio 2015 C# project, is there any way to selectively install the components of a NuGet package? *(Aside from manually adding references)*

---

**Background:**

I have been using the `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp` package recently.  This package contains several libraries that I need:

- `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis`
- `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp`

It also installs many libraries that these are dependent on.  For the features I am using, I only need these two:

- `System.Collections.Immutable`
- `System.Reflection.Metadata`

But it also installs many more libraries that I never need:

- `System.AppContext`
- `System.ComponentModel.Composition`
- `System.Console`
- `System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo`
- `System.Diagnostics.StackTrace`
- `System.IO.FileSystem`
- `System.IO.FileSystem.Primatives`
- `System.Numerics`
- `System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms`
- `System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding`
- `System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives`
- `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates`
- `System.Text.Encoding.CodePages`
- `System.Threading.Thread`
- `System.Xml`
- `System.Xml.Linq`
- `System.Xml.XmlDocument`
- `System.Xml.XPath`
- `Systen.Xml.XPath.XDocument`

Is there someway I can check the boxes of the libraries I want when installing the package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/tools/powershell-reference#install-package) , there only *-IgnoreDependencies* command could help us **ignore all dependencies**. We could not ignore part of dependencies.

But you could implement your requirement with *-IgnoreDependencies*, please refer to following steps:

1. Install the Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp package without any dependence:

   *Install-Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp -IgnoreDependencies*
2. Install the dependence package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis. Common package without any dependence:

   *Install-Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common -IgnoreDependencies*
3. Install the dependence package System.Collections.Immutable and System.Reflection.Metadata package:

   *Install-Package System.Collections.Immutable*

   *Install-Package System.Reflection.Metadata*

If you do not need to use the dependences of “System.Collections.Immutable”and “System.Reflection.Metadata”, you can also use the same option to ignore dependences.